# startMonitoringForRegion vs startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Tags: ios, bluetooth, location

Im building a simple ios app with IBeacon, Im using startMonitoringForRegion for detect beacons.

[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];

That's ok. My problem is that i want to check if the bluetooth is ON or OFF. If the bluetooth is OFF i want to check periodically if the user is near a network of beacons and send a notification suggesting to activate de bluetooth. For that purpose im using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.

[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

The problem is that both methods calls didUpdateLocations, so im sending multiple notifications. Can i determinate if this method is called by startMonitoringForRegion or startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges uses locationManager:didUpdateLocations: callback

while startMonitoringForRegion: uses locationManager:didEnterRegion:(didExitRegion) callback

See reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:

Comment: I check only using startMonitoringForRegion: and locationManager:didUpdateLocations: callback is also called.

Comment: Do you call startUpdatingLocation?

Comment: Yes, on the method didEnterRegion: i have startRangingBeaconsInRegion and startUpdatingLocation.[manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
Maybe the startUpdatingLocation is not necessary here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in didEnterRegion: callback i have startRangingBeaconsInRegion and startUpdatingLocation.

```
[manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*) region]; 
//[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

The second one is no necessary for me, so i comment that line and it works ok. didUpdateLocations: callback now its only fired by startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.